# height of router-outlet in angular2

Tags: angular

I got some problem that I wanna to design a frame that slice like `flex:1` and `flex:2`.

Separated the frame and Want the left component got same height as right compoment.(If right side height is smaller than left one, left one show `100%`).

**pug**

```
.container(style='display:flex')
  .leftside(style='flex:1')
    some-component
  .rightside(style='flex:4')
    router-outlet
```

I implemented jquery before that the left component is rendered completely and quirk the `scrollClient`,hence I set the `service(injectable)` and observe on `router.event` when got `navigatorEnd`.

Precisely,I want to got `scrollheight` of  `router-outlet`, but returns `0` every single time.

**service.ts(export Toolservice)**

```
private routerHeight:number;
constructor(private router: Router) {
  this.router.events
    .filter(event => event instanceof NavigationEnd)
    .subscribe((event) => {
      this.routerHeight = document.getElementsByTagName('router-outlet')[0].scrollHeight;
    });
}

newheight(){ return this.routerHeight;}
```

**some-component.ts**

```
constructor(private toolservice:Toolservice,private el:ElementRef){}
getNewHeight(){
    this.el.nativeElement.height = this.toolservice.newheight();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The `<router-outlet>` tag itself has no height, it's a placeholder tag, and the content is placed -below- it, not inside it. Strange and not 'angular' code aside, you can use the `nextElementSibling` property I guess:

```
this.routerHeight = document.getElementsByTagName('router-outlet')[0].nextElementSibling.scrollHeight;
```

Comment: it works thanks! I thought the component is rendered router-outlet inside but is didn't!

Answer (score 3):

Well, I think You can put `router-outlet` inside a `div` and get `scrollHeight` of that div.

```
<div>
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

Comment: wrap the `div` isn't good  solution that why the ng-template implement.

Comment: it's great solution then i try your frame . I subscribe the outer `div` height and it works well and simple.

Comment: I use window:resize in service.